# How to send a DM to a specific user ID on a sharded discord.js bot?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I have a discord bot, and I need to send a DM to a specific user id (notification, etc). The bot is sharded, so it makes this more advanced. What would be the best way to do this?

I'm not sure of what I can do to do this. I just recently enabled sharding on my bot, and it's quite hard to get all the commands, functions etc converted to work with sharding, so looking for some good advice to get it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand how to send a message to a given user ID when sharding, we have to understand how to send a message based on a user ID with or without sharding. You probably know how to do this with the websocket client (the `Client` class), but you might not know how to do it with the REST api. These first two large sections are dedicated to each of these. Skip whatever information you don't need, but there are some interesting facts sprinkled within, like the existence of `createDM` in the gateway API `User`/`UserManager` objects.

## Using a Websocket Client to Interact With Users

This is probably information you already know, but it's good to put it here for others who might not know, especially those who may be sharding before even doing something like this.

Fetching users with a client (for websocket-based bots) is quite simple. The [`Client`](https://old.discordjs.dev/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/Client) class has the [`users`](https://old.discordjs.dev/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/Client?scrollTo=users) member on all instances. This `users` member is a [`UserManager`](https://old.discordjs.dev/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/UserManager) instance, which has a variety of ways to interact with users.

### Creating DM Channels With Users

The [`createDM`](https://old.discordjs.dev/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/UserManager?scrollTo=createDM) method is an odd method. It [`promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)s to return a [`DMChannel`](https://old.discordjs.dev/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/DMChannel), a channel which can be used to communicate with the user. We can then send to this channel as we would any text channel:

```js
// `client` is an instance of Client. `id` is some ID or other way to identify a user.
let dmChannel = await client.users.createDM(id);
dmChannel.send("This is a message.");
```

We `await` the call to `client.users.createDM` because it returns a promise; because the information isn't available right away, we ask to wait and get the information directly instead of a promise to the information. In this case, the information is a `DMChannel`.

#### Deleting the DM Channels

This is entirely unrelated, but `UserManager` also has a [`deleteDM`](https://old.discordjs.dev/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/UserManager?scrollTo=deleteDM) method.  All this does is delete the dm channel with a user *if it exists*, and it returns a promise to the `DMChannel`. It only resolves to the channel if successful, so I'm guessing that this mainly deletes the channel *from the cache*, so it doesn't take up unnecessary memory.

### Fetching Users Themselves

The `fetch` method of the `UserManager` is the most common way of getting a user by ID. The method takes in a `UserResolvable`, which is anything that can be used to identify a user. Sorry for not linking this one-- I can't use any more links due to low reputation. We can then `await` the promise and either treat them as a channel or *call `User`'s very own `createDM` method*.

```js
// Again, `id` in our case is an ID, but it can even be a User, Message, GuildMember
// (user in a server), or a ThreadMember (GuildMember in a thread).
let userInstance = await client.users.fetch(id);
userInstance.send("This is also a message.");
```

Alternatively, we could use this:

```js
let userInstance = await client.users.fetch(id);
let dmChannel = await userInstance.createDM();
dmChannel.send("This is yet another message.");
```

The method of using `fetch` is useful due to the fact that it provides *the user itself*. This way, you could use information about the user *in the message*.

### Directly Indexing the Cache

Don't do this. This is only here for informational purposes, and it only works if you know for granted that the user is cached, which is rarely guaranteed.

`UserManager`'s `cache` member is nothing more than a collection of keys and values where the keys are user ids (NOT users, thread members, etc.) and the values are users themselves. Think of this as a `Map<Snowflake, User>`, or even more generically, an object (`{ ... }`) with user ids for keys and users for values. Use the `at` method to index into the cache.

```js
// `id` is ONLY a user id this time. It CANNOT be anything else.
let cachedUser = client.users.cache.at(id)
cachedUser.send("This is a message to a user found in the cache.")
```

Again, because `cachedUser` is a `User`, we could use the `cachedUser.createDM` method to create a channel that we can use to send messages to the user.

## Using the API Modules to Interact With Users

The documentation for the API modules can be found [here](https://discord.js.org/docs/packages/core/1.0.1).
We're interested specifically in two modules `UsersAPI` and `ChannelsAPI`. Something to note: every function returns data **without methods.** That means that the "`APIUser`" class doesn't have either the `createDM` or `send` methods. This is why we need both API modules.

Before using either of these, we need to instantiate them.

```js
import { REST } from '@discordjs/rest'
import { UsersAPI, ChannelsAPI } from '@discordjs/core'
const rest = new REST({ version: 10 /* API Version. */})
                      .setToken(/* token */);
const users = new UsersAPI(rest);
const channels = new ChannelsAPI(rest);
```

Assume these variables exist here.

### Fetching User Information

The `UsersAPI` allows us to fetch information about users and their DM channels. This is because `UsersAPI` covers most of the `/api/users` endpoints found on Discord's developer documentation. The `UsersAPI` has both a `get` method, for getting users, and a `createDM` method, for getting the DM channel for a user. If the goal is simply to message the user, you only need to use the `createDM` method. If you need more information on the user, like name, account age, etc., use the `get` method as well.

#### `UsersAPI` `get` Method

This method gets information on the user. Again, only use this if you need information other than the DM channel.

```js
// id is ONLY the user id.
let user = await users.get(id);
```

#### `UsersAPI` `createDM` Method

This method is actually necessary for messaging the user. There is no other way (to my knowledge) to get the channel for messaging the user.

```js
// id is ONLY the user id.
let userChannel = await users.createDM(id);
```

### Sending Messages with `ChannelsAPI`

There is one way to send messages unless we are cross-posting a message, but we are not. `ChannelsAPI.createMessage` takes in a channel ID and a message body. The body is either the JSON representation of a message (`{ content: ..., ... }`) or the JSON representation with an additional `files` member that is a list `RawFile` objects. These objects contain a file name and some data in the form of a `Buffer`, `Uint8Array`, `boolean`, `number`, or `string`. See the documentation for more information.

```js
let userChannel = await users.createDM(id);
let channelId = userChannel.id;
const messageJSON = { content: "Effectively a direct call to the API" };
let responseMessage = channels.createMessage(channelId, messageJSON);
```

Again, I do not believe there is another way to send a message using the API modules. Now, let's talk about how this can be used with sharding.

## Sending a Scheduled Reminder to a User

Let's use the example of a scheduled reminder. Furthermore, let's suppose we have a database that we know how to use. When the user asks us to schedule a reminder, we'll write a certain entry in the database. This entry will contain a user id, a UNIX timestamp in milliseconds, and a title/description of the reminder. Let's suppose that in JSON, the entry would look like this:

```json
{
  "user_id": "1234567890",
  "timestamp": "1695211284000",
  "description": "Walk the dog."
}
```

`timestamp` has trailing zeroes because the JavaScript `Date` object uses milliseconds. Now, let's assume we've already done the heavy work of knowing when to send the reminder; if you want to know about that, there are plenty of tutorials online that can help, but for now, let's avoid getting side-tracked.

First, let's look at how to do this without communicating to our shards.

### Sending the Reminder Outside the Shard

Let's define a function, `sendReminder`. It'll take in the reminder information, and we'll call it whenever we send a reminder. Note that **we should do all of the reminder checking outside a shard**. As long as this is all happening in the same file as our `ShardingManager` and ***not*** the shard script file, the reminders will only be run once.

Again, your main file should contain:

- The ShardingManager
- The Reminder Code
- Other things to only run once

Your shard scripts should only contain clients and client information. **Do not put any reminder-related code except the code to create reminders in shard scripts or files required by shard scripts.** This will likely cause multiple shards to send the reminder, which is not what we want.

Now, let's write `sendReminder`:

```js
/* Up here should be our ShardingManager as well as any other code*/
const rest = new REST({ version: 10 /* API Version. */})
                      .setToken(/* token */);
const users = new UsersAPI(rest);
const channels = new ChannelsAPI(rest);
// I'm using arrow notation, but you can use whatever you'd like
const sendReminder = async reminder => {
  // Check if it's actually time to send the reminder.
  // If the timestamp is greater than the current time, it's too early.
  if (new Date(reminder.timestamp) > Date.now())
    return;

  // Otherwise, let's send the reminder.
  let user = await users.get(reminder.user_id);
  let channel = await users.createDM(reminder.user_id);
  const message = {
    content: `Dear <@${user.id}>, your reminder, ${reminder.description}, has elapsed. Please take appropriate action.`
  };
  channels.createMessage(channel.id, message);
};
```

The `<@${user.id}>` is just a way to create a mention to the user, as that is the way mentions are stored internally by Discord, with a few niches. This method is much cleaner than telling a single shard to send the message. For informational purposes, let's see how that might work anyway.

### Sending the Reminder Through a Shard

Again, I don't recommend this. It's quite bad, really, and its only advantage is its use of familiar functions.

#### The Main File

The main file (the part with `ShardingManager`) still needs its own code. This is because if the shards themselves handled everything, they'd probably all simultaneously send the reminders and try to delete database entries. This is not good. Instead, we'll still have a `sendReminder`, but this will get a shard and tell that shard to run a function.

Actually, the main file is *all* we have to write in. The third-level header is simply misleading.

```js
// suppose `manager` is our ShardManager
const sendReminder = reminder => {
  if (new Date(reminder.timestamp) > Date.now())
    return;
  // manager.shards is a collection of shards.
  // .random() gives us a random one. We can select
  // the first one with .first(), or a number of other methods.
  let shard = manager.shards.random();
  shard.eval(async c => { // `c` is the basic DiscordJS client.
    let user = await c.users.fetch(reminder.id);
    await user.send(`Hello, <@${user.id}>. Your reminder, ${reminder.description}, has elapsed. Please take appropriate action.`);
  })
}
```

This is a splendid function. What we've done here is verified that we should
send the reminder now, get a random shard, and tell that shard to run a function. The function it runs will fetch the user and send the reminder.

Now, let's do something even uglier: dedicating a single shard to do everything.

### Dedicating a Single Shard to Handle All Reminder Sending

Please, don't do this. It introduces problems like "what if my shard dies?" and other wonderful problems. If something goes wrong, you shouldn't let it be in the child processes or worker threads.

Let's write some code in our shard scripts. Assume `client` is the name of our discord client.

```js
/* Above, write the code to start the bot */

// If this 'shard' handles shard 0
if (client.shard.ids.includes(0)) {
  reminderCode();
}

const reminderCode = () => {
  // Place the code that gets the next reminder and calls sendReminder
  // accordingly here.
};

const sendReminder = async reminder => {
  if (new Date(reminder.timestamp) > Date.now)
    return;

  let user = client.users.fetch(reminder.id);
  await user.send(`Hello, <@${user.id}>, your reminder, **${reminder.description}** has elapsed. Please take appropriate action.`);
};
```

Wonderful. What this code does is it checks if the current shard is the *first* shard. If so, it runs all of the code that makes the other two examples identify when to send a reminder. Then, we have our own `sendReminder` function that checks the date and has direct access to the client. No need to send messages to shards!

Just make sure that in the main file, if shard 0 dies, to respawn the shard. Even better, if any shard dies, make sure to respawn it.

```js
// `manager` is the ShardManager
manager.spawn().then(shards =>
  shards.forEach(shard => {
    shard.on('death', proc => {
      shard.respawn()
    });
}));
```

## Conclusion

Sharding is all about splitting the work between multiple processes. Each shard only does a portion of the work, and each shard is its own process. It's dangerous to tell every shard to do something because this can cause multiple shards to send the same message and try to delete database records, which could lead to errors and rate-limiting.

It's best to handle things without relying on shards when possible. For example, when you're regularly checking a database for entries with timestamps in the past, it's best to do that on a central process rather than a child process (a shard). When it comes time to send the message, it's better to also directly call the API to send the message rather than ask a shard (which could very well be dead or overloaded) to do it for us.

If we really need to delegate this process to a shard, we can place code in our shard scripts that checks if that shard has a given id. If it does, then we'll run the code to regularly check the database and send messages accordingly without the need to send messages between processes.

Apologies for the **enormous** answer, but it's actually a bit more complex than it would first seem, and I wanted to provide context for the ways that we can send messages to arbitrary (or stored) user ids.

Comment: Thank you really for your time in writing this answer. You've practically fixed all problems and all future problems for this for me, originally I was just going to try to send all DMs through shard 0 but you've given me a much better way. And actually you've pretty much fixed some other issues I was going to have such as banning people "globally" with a cache to find where they are from. I'll be sending DMs and bans via the rest API as this is clearly the best way

Comment: @EddieToth You're very welcome! _was_ going to provide an answer like Jaxon Watt's with more detail (like the REST API), but then I realized that you were asking about avoiding multiple messages. Thank **you** for asking a question that made me appreciate Discord.JS's structure even more, despite my having moved on from Discord.JS almost a year ago. If you have more problems in the future, I'll be sure to look out for them.

Answer (score -1):

You send users direct messages with the [user.send()](https://old.discordjs.dev/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/User?scrollTo=send) function

Like this

```
<user>.send(message)
```

You will have to fetch the user from your client or get it from its cache:

```
<client>.users.fetch(id)
```

or

```
<client>.users.cache.get(id)
```